# ESS dendrograms: appearance of last branch

Tags: character-encoding, ess, characters

In R it is possible to customise the appearance of a [dendrogram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dendrogram) and set a custom start character for the last branches. According to the documentation:

> In some environments, using `'` will provide much nicer looking output, than the historical default `` ` ``.

Emacs ESS does just this and, in [`ess-s-l.el`](https://github.com/emacs-ess/ESS/blob/master/lisp/ess-s-l.el), sets the option `str.dendrogram.last` to a single quote. It is a sort of strict requirement, in fact, contrary to the Emacs ESS philosophy (where everything can be customised), this setting is hardcoded in `ess-s-l.el` and is difficult to override. Therefore I assume that Emacs is one of those environments where single quotes *look much nicer* than backticks.

Anyway, in my current Windows Emacs version, backticks look perfect and I am going (trying) to get rid of it.
However I wonder whether there is some situation where backticks might display poorly or it is a problem showed in some old Emacs version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to set `str.dendrogram.last` to "`"? That can be done from R using the `last.str` argument to `str()`:

```
str(dend1, max = 2, last.str =  "`")
```

or, it can be set using the function

```
options(str.dendrogram.last = "`")
```

You can add the `options()` call to your .Rprofile file to have it loaded automatically, which should over-ride the setting imposed by ESS.

Whether this displays poorly or not will depend on the font you are using.

Comment: Actually I just would like to understand _why_ they set the single quotation. I think there should be a specific reason to override R defaults.

Comment: The ESS group is pretty active, you could ask them directly.